# How to use Permissions work in discord.py?

Tags: python, permissions, discord, discord.py

I am currently working on a discord bot in python using discord.py. I am currently trying to add a feature in which the user can check what perms the bot has.

The output should look like this, but right now I am unsure how to get the actual info. If anyone knows how I could do this it would be great. Thanks.

[image: expected output]

Answer (score 1):

You can get the bot's permissions using [`Member.guild_permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.guild_permissions)

```
@client.command()
async def perms(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    user = guild.get_member(client.user.id)
    for perm in user.guild_permissions:
        perm_list = list(perm)
        print(f"{perm_list[0]} ---> {perm_list[1]}")
```

Output:

```
create_instant_invite ---> True
kick_members ---> True
ban_members ---> True
administrator ---> False
manage_channels ---> True
manage_guild ---> True
add_reactions ---> True
view_audit_log ---> True
priority_speaker ---> False
stream ---> True
read_messages ---> True
send_messages ---> False
send_tts_messages ---> False
manage_messages ---> False
embed_links ---> False
attach_files ---> False
read_message_history ---> False
mention_everyone ---> False
external_emojis ---> True
view_guild_insights ---> False
connect ---> True
speak ---> True
mute_members ---> False
deafen_members ---> False
move_members ---> False
use_voice_activation ---> True
change_nickname ---> True
manage_nicknames ---> True
manage_roles ---> True
manage_webhooks ---> True
manage_emojis ---> True
```